# Tricky conditional transform values per row based on logic of another column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to round EACH VALUE to the nearest even # so that our row sum doesn't exceed or go below the 'rounded_sum' column value for that row.
If we exceed or go below, compensate for the difference by subtracting or adding the difference to one of the values. Making sure no negative values.

**Data**

```
Location    range     type  Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28   rounded_sum
NY          low re    AA    1.14    0       0       0       2
NY          low re    BB    0       0       0       0       0
NY          low re    DD    0.51    2       4       0       6
NY          low re    SS    0       0       0       0       0
NY          low stat  AA    1.03    2       2       4       10
NY          low stat  BB    0.45    0       2       2       4
NY          low stat  DD    1.53    2       4       6       14
NY          low stat  SS    0.26    0       0       2       2
CA          low re    AA    0.34    0       2       0       2
CA          low re    BB    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low re    DD    0.69    0       2       0       2
CA          low re    SS    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low stat  AA    0.18    0       0       2       2
CA          low stat  BB    0.2     0       0       0       0
CA          low stat  DD    0.27    0       0       2       2
CA          low stat  SS    0.04    0       0       0       0
```

**Desired**

```
Location    range     type  Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28   rounded_sum
NY          low re    AA    2       0       0       0       2
NY          low re    BB    0       0       0       0       0
NY          low re    DD    0       2       4       0       6
NY          low re    SS    0       0       0       0       0
NY          low stat  AA    2       2       2       4       10
NY          low stat  BB    0       0       2       2       4
NY          low stat  DD    2       2       4       6       14
NY          low stat  SS    0       0       0       2       2
CA          low re    AA    0       0       2       0       2
CA          low re    BB    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low re    DD    0       0       2       0       2
CA          low re    SS    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low stat  AA    0       0       0       2       2
CA          low stat  BB    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low stat  DD    0       0       0       2       2
CA          low stat  SS    0       0       0       0       0
```

**Doing**

```
arr1 = df.iloc[:, 3:].values
s1 = np.sum(arr1, axis=1)
s1 = np.where(s1 < 0.5, 0, np.ceil(s1 / 2) * 2)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: This sounds more like an optimization problem than a pandas problem to me. You could probably heuristically do this, but an LP solver would make this much easier.

Comment: I see - what is an LP solver? figured I can apply Pandas to create a conditions @StuSztukowski

Comment: An LP solver is a Linear Programming solver that helps solve optimization problems. For example, you can define your objective to minimize the average difference between all values in a row, and constrain it such that (1) it can only add or subtract from one value, (2) the value can never be negative, and (3) the sum of each row must add up to the rounded sum. There are python packages that do this but you'll have to learn how to formulate the problem for it.

Comment: ah I see ok thank you @StuSztukowski - will keep researching this, as I prefer to implement 100% using Pandas/Python

Comment: No problem, I'd love to help you with it but I only know how to solve it in another non-Python optimization language. If I think of how to do this heuristically in Pandas I'll post an answer. I'm thinking it'll need to be a row-by-row operation that tries to add or subtract from the smallest or largest value.

Comment: this makes sense - thank you @StuSztukowski appreciate the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. We will add to or subtract from the smallest or greatest value depending on whether the sum of `Q1-Q4` is less than or greater than the rounded sum.

```
cols     = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
df[cols] = df[cols].round().astype('int')

unequal_sums_filter = df[cols].sum(axis=1) != df['rounded_sum']

# Only make changes to the rows where the sum is not equal to the rounded sum
for idx, row in df[unequal_sums_filter].iterrows():

    # Find the min/max cols and the sum of the row
    max_col = row[cols].astype(float).idxmax()
    min_col = row[cols].astype(float).idxmin()
    sum_row = row[cols].sum()

    # Get the biggest value and subtract the difference from it. 
    # Otherwise, get the smallest value and add the difference to it.
    if sum_row > row['rounded_sum']:
        df.loc[idx, max_col] = row.loc[max_col] - (sum_row - row['rounded_sum'])
    else:
        df.loc[idx, min_col] = row.loc[min_col] + (row['rounded_sum'] - sum_row)

df['check'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
```

```
   Location       range    type  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  rounded_sum  check
0        NY      low re      AA   2   0   0   0            2      2
1        NY      low re      BB   0   0   0   0            0      0
2        NY      low re      DD   1   2   3   0            6      6
3        NY      low re      SS   0   0   0   0            0      0
4        NY      low stat    AA   1   2   2   5           10     10
5        NY      low stat    BB   0   0   2   2            4      4
6        NY      low stat    DD   2   2   4   6           14     14
7        NY      low stat    SS   0   0   0   2            2      2
8        CA      low re      AA   0   0   2   0            2      2
9        CA      low re      BB   0   0   0   0            0      0
10       CA      low re      DD   1   0   1   0            2      2
11       CA      low re      SS   0   0   0   0            0      0
12       CA      low stat    AA   0   0   0   2            2      2
13       CA      low stat    BB   0   0   0   0            0      0
14       CA      low stat    DD   0   0   0   2            2      2
15       CA      low stat    SS   0   0   0   0            0      0
```

Comment: Thanks @Stu I’ll try this solution out and modify if need be

Comment: thank you @stu this is a brilliant solution - would like to buy coffee

Comment: Glad to hear! I started working on a solution that didn't use `df.itterrows()`, but it started getting pretty complex looking. As long as your data is small then the performance of it should be just fine. In general I try to avoid using it but in this case it seemed appropriate, especially for readability.